# Почему не показывается картинка в нужном размере

Tags: php

Ребят скажите пожалуйста почему у меня картинки не выводятся в заданных px, а на сайте только оригинал выводится. Че не так в этом коде?

```
if ($row["imagesad"] != "" && file_exists("ph_main/" . $row["imagesad"])) {
    $img_path = 'ph_main/' . $row["imagesad"];
    $max_width = 114;
    $max_height = 105;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path);
    $ratioh = $max_height / $height;
    $ratiow = $max_width / $width;
    $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
    $width = intval($ratio * $width);
    $height = intval($ratio * $height);
} else {
    $img_path = "images/no-image.png";
    $width = 110;
    $height = 200;
}

echo '
<li>
    <div class="block-images-grid">
        <img src="ph_main/' . $row[" imagesad"] . '">
    </div>
    <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">' . $row["title"] . '</a></p>
    <ul class="reviews-and-counts-grid">
        <li><img src="images/eye-icon.png">
            <p>0</p></li>
        <li><img src="images/comment-icon.png">
            <p>0</p></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="style-price-grid"><strong></strong></p>
    <div class="mini-features">
        <p>Город:</p>
        <p>Дата:</p>
    </div>
</li>
';
}
```

Comment: А использовать вычисленные переменные `$img_path`, `$width` и `$height` нельзя в коде?

Comment: не могли бы показать пример? буду очень благодарен:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно говорил [@Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman). Вы вычисляете данные для картинки, но не используете их.
Если код писали вы, я не понимаю, какие трудности вы испытываете при его использовании.

Вот ваш пример с подставленными переменными:

```
echo '
<li>
    <div class="block-images-grid">
        <img src="' . $img_path . '" style="width:' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height. 'px;">
    </div>
    <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">' . $row["title"] . '</a></p>
    <ul class="reviews-and-counts-grid">
        <li><img src="images/eye-icon.png">
            <p>0</p></li>
        <li><img src="images/comment-icon.png">
            <p>0</p></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="style-price-grid"><strong></strong></p>
    <div class="mini-features">
        <p>Город:</p>
        <p>Дата:</p>
    </div>
</li>
';
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Нет код писал не я, я его только переделываю, смотрел видео, дак там он вот так токо писал. Спасибо вам еще раз!